# Декоратор класса в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, декоратор

```
def func(class_name):
  my_name = f"{self.obj}"

@func
class C(obj): 
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
```

Этот код чисто идея, он нерабочий естественно. Как сделать декоратор класса С? То есть в декораторе я хочу по сути добавить поле класса my_name, например, означающий строковое представление поля value. Но как бы проблема в том, что для каждого экземпляра класса имя свое, то есть нужно init переопределять? И как в декораторе получить доступ к полю value если у меня есть только имя класса? Есть подсказка сделать через non-data descriptor, правда очень смутно понимаю как.

Answer (score 2):

Вы неверно понимаете декораторы.

Декоратор, во-первых, принимает в качестве аргумента не "имя класса", а сам класс, как объект. И, во-вторых, декоратор обязательно должен возвращать тоже класс.

Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите, то это можно сделать так:

```
def func(cls):

    old_init = cls.__init__

    def new_init(self, value):
        old_init(self, value)
        self.my_name = str(value)

    cls.__init__ = new_init

    return cls


@func
class C(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


c = C(value=123)
print(c.my_name)  # Напечатает: 123
```

Comment: а если допустим класс будет наследоваться от list, а value это строка? old_init тогда не будет работать из-за несоответствия типов. И при вызове old_init внутри new_init кажется не нужен self в параметрах

Comment: @iamhdq, self нужен, в init всегда передаётся self, явно или не явно. Про наследование от list - я не понял, в чём вы видите проблему, и какой вообще результат хотите получить. Потрудитесь нормально сформулировать вашу задачу, чтобы я тут не играл в угадайку.